# Advanced Grouping - Pulling most recent transaction, but maintaining grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I have a fairly complex query that I can't seem to get correct group by-wise. Everything is running smoothly except for the grouping. The issue is that there are products, and sub products that I need to pull sums from, but I also need to pull the most recent transaction as there are 'duplicates' (they are not really duplicate rows, but not pulling the most recent transaction will inflate the sums drastically). To be more specific, I am pulling the most recent transaction by inner joining the most recent transaction with what I am selecting from the table:

```
INNER JOIN (select fp.pol_num
                      ,MAX(fp.id_prem) id_prem
                 from bapu.dbo.fact_prem fp
                 group by fp.pol_num) max_trans_id
        on fp.pol_num = max_trans_id.pol_num
       and fp.id_prem = max_trans_id.id_prem
```

This is what is messing up my grouping. What is happening is that the sums for all 'amts' are being stuck in a row with the sub product that is most recent. So for example, if a policy has 3 coverages: General Liability, Commercial Auto, and Workers Comp, the sums for all three of those coverages are being added to only the last row that was edited. I need to maintain the structure of product - sub product so each sub product has the correct sum rather than the sum for all 3 being displayed for one sub product type. I have tried changing the subquery that pulls the most recent transaction, and the group by statement but that only seems to make things work. Here is the query that I am running:

```
DECLARE @d_inforce date; SET @d_inforce = '2014-06-01'


select limit_group_list.limit_group as 'Limit Band'
      ,pol_dtl.product
      ,pol_dtl.sub_product
      ,SUM(COALESCE(pol_dtl.gross_premium,0)) as 'Gross Premium'
      ,COUNT(distinct pol_dtl.pol_num) as 'Policy Count'
      ,SUM(COALESCE(pol_dtl.limit,0)) as 'Limit'
from
(select pol_product.pol_num
      ,pol_product.product
      ,pol_product.sub_product
      ,pol_premcomm.gross_premium
      ,pol_premcomm.commission
      ,pol_premcomm.net_premium
      ,pol_limit.lmt_pol_s as limit
      ,pol_limit.Limit_Order
      ,pol_limit.Limit_Group
from
-- Pull product for each policy from the most recent transaction
(select fp.pol_num
       ,fp.product
       ,fp.sub_product
 from bapu.dbo.fact_prem fp
 INNER JOIN (select fp.pol_num
                   ,MAX(fp.id_prem) id_prem
             from bapu.dbo.fact_prem fp
             group by fp.pol_num) max_trans_id
    on fp.pol_num = max_trans_id.pol_num
   and fp.id_prem = max_trans_id.id_prem
 -- Inforce Logic
 where @d_inforce between fp.d_pol_eff and fp.d_pol_exp
   and fp.pol_num not in (select distinct pol_num from bapu.dbo.fact_prem where lower(trans) like 'canc%' and d_tran_eff <= @d_inforce)
) pol_product
LEFT OUTER JOIN
-- Pull premium, commission, and net_premium per policy number
(select prem_comm.pol_num as pol_num
       ,prem_comm.gross_premium as gross_premium
       ,prem_comm.commission as commission
       ,COALESCE(prem_comm.gross_premium,0) - COALESCE(prem_comm.commission,0) as net_premium
 from
 (select fp.pol_num
        ,SUM(CASE
               WHEN fp.amt_type = 'Premium' THEN fp.amt
               ELSE 0
             END) as gross_premium
        ,SUM(CASE
               WHEN fp.amt_type = 'Add_Ded' and fp.amt_desc = 'Commission' THEN fp.amt
               ELSE 0
             END) as commission
  from bapu.dbo.fact_prem fp
 group by fp.pol_num) prem_comm) pol_premcomm
ON pol_product.pol_num = pol_premcomm.pol_num
LEFT OUTER JOIN
-- Pull limit bands per policy
    (SELECT pol_lmt.pol_num
      ,pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s
      ,CASE 
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 50000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <= 100000000 THEN 20
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 40000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  50000000 THEN 19
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 30000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  40000000 THEN 18
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 20000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  30000000 THEN 17
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 15000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  20000000 THEN 16
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 14000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  15000000 THEN 15
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 13000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  14000000 THEN 14
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 12000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  13000000 THEN 13
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 11000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  12000000 THEN 12
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 10000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  11000000 THEN 11
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  9000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  10000000 THEN 10
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  8000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   9000000 THEN 9
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  7000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   8000000 THEN 8
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  6000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   7000000 THEN 7
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  5000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   6000000 THEN 6
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  4000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   5000000 THEN 5
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  3000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   4000000 THEN 4
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  2000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   3000000 THEN 3
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  1000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   2000000 THEN 2
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=        1 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   1000000 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END AS Limit_Order
      ,CASE 
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 50000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <= 100000000 THEN '$50,000,001-$100,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 40000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  50000000 THEN '$40,000,001-$50,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 30000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  40000000 THEN '$30,000,001-$40,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 20000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  30000000 THEN '$20,000,001-$30,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 15000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  20000000 THEN '$15,000,001-$20,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 14000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  15000000 THEN '$14,000,001-$15,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 13000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  14000000 THEN '$13,000,001-$14,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 12000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  13000000 THEN '$12,000,001-$13,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 11000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  12000000 THEN '$11,000,001-$12,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >= 10000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  11000000 THEN '$10,000,001-$11,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  9000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=  10000000 THEN '$9,000,001-$10,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  8000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   9000000 THEN '$8,000,001-$9,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  7000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   8000000 THEN '$7,000,001-$8,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  6000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   7000000 THEN '$6,000,001-$7,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  5000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   6000000 THEN '$5,000,001-$6,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  4000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   5000000 THEN '$4,000,001-$5,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  3000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   4000000 THEN '$3,000,001-$4,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  2000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   3000000 THEN '$2,000,001-$3,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=  1000001 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   2000000 THEN '$1,000,001-$2,000,000'
        WHEN pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s >=        1 AND pol_lmt.lmt_pol_s <=   1000000 THEN '$0-$1,000,000'

        ELSE 'Unknown' 
      END AS Limit_Group
    FROM 
      (select fp.pol_num
             ,MAX(lmt_pol_s) lmt_pol_s
       from bapu.dbo.fact_prem fp
       where fp.amt_type = 'Premium'
       and fp.product in (
'Package',
'Package - Crime',
'Package - Fine Art',
'Package - Jewelers Block',
'Package - Specie')
       group by fp.pol_num) pol_lmt
       ) pol_limit

 ON pol_product.pol_num = pol_limit.pol_num
 where pol_product.product in (
'Package',
'Package - Crime',
'Package - Fine Art',
'Package - Jewelers Block',
'Package - Specie')
 and pol_product.sub_product in(
                        'Umbrella/Excess',
                        'Workers Compensation',
                        'General Liability',
                        'Commercial Auto',
                        'Commercial Property')
                        ) as pol_dtl
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(select distinct fp.product 
               ,lmtgrp.limit_group
from bapu.dbo.fact_prem fp
cross join
(select '$50,000,001-$100,000,000' limit_group
 UNION
 select '$40,000,001-$50,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$30,000,001-$40,000,000'
  UNION
 select '$20,000,001-$30,000,000'
  UNION
 select '$15,000,001-$20,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$14,000,001-$15,000,000'
 UNION 
 select '$13,000,001-$14,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$12,000,001-$13,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$11,000,001-$12,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$10,000,001-$11,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$9,000,001-$10,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$8,000,001-$9,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$7,000,001-$8,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$6,000,001-$7,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$5,000,001-$6,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$4,000,001-$5,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$3,000,001-$4,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$2,000,001-$3,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$1,000,001-$2,000,000'
 UNION
 select '$0-$1,000,000'
 UNION
 select 'Unknown') lmtgrp
 where  fp.product in (
'Package',
'Package - Crime',
'Package - Fine Art',
'Package - Jewelers Block',
'Package - Specie')
  and fp.sub_product in(
                        'Umbrella/Excess',
                        'Workers Compensation',
                        'General Liability',
                        'Commercial Auto',
                        'Commercial Property')              
 ) limit_group_list
 on pol_dtl.product = limit_group_list.product
and pol_dtl.Limit_Group = limit_group_list.limit_group
group by pol_dtl.Limit_Group, pol_dtl.Limit_Order, pol_dtl.product, limit_group_list.limit_group, sub_product
order by pol_dtl.product, pol_dtl.Limit_Order
```

Comment: Can you give sample data with expected result & actual result?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that do not use the same alias for tables and subqueries (fp) this make it hard to follow :S

Second, you can replace the group / max query with the following query to get the most recent row

```
INNER JOIN (select subfp.pol_num
                 , subfp.id_prem
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY subfp.pol_num ORDER BY subfp.id_prem DESC) AS priority
             from bapu.dbo.fact_prem subfp
             ) max_trans_id
    on fp.pol_num = max_trans_id.pol_num
   and fp.id_prem = max_trans_id.id_prem
   and max_trans_id.priority = 1
```

I hope this helps